# Is list-style: initial an official supported value

Tags: html, css

Today I was extending my CSS a little bit for an anchor navigation with numbered listitems.
Since I reset my list items in a normalise.css I had to specify the default value to the list-style property

In most cases 'default', does the trick. But today in Chrome developer tools I noticed this wasn't the case for 'list-style'. Code hinting in Chrome showed me the value 'initial'. I have never seen that property before, w3.org doesn't talk about it and sublime text 2 isn't highlighting it.

Is this some kind of a new unofficial value?

```
nav.anchor-navigation ol {
    list-style: initial;
}
```

Comment: First hit for "CSS initial": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Comment: (`default`, on the other hand, is not a CSS keyword.)

Comment: FWIW, Opera *should* support `initial` in the versions that use Blink, as Blink derives its `initial` implementation from WebKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`list-style` is supported in all modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) (and [here it is in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style)), but [`initial` is not supported on IE and Opera.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) (specification: [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#keywords) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial))

They are "official" values, however, if by "official" you mean they are in the specification.

Comment: You might want to actually link to the specification instead.

Comment: @BoltClock The specs are linked on the pages I linked to.

Comment: Yeah but if you're going to say that they're in the specification, why not just link directly to the specification?